# Dialog is not a function - React

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, reactjs, react-dom

I know there are a lot of questions about this already but none of them seem to match my problem.

I am creating a React component using `JQuery-UI dialog`
It looks like this:

```
var VehiclePlantDialog = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.closeDialog();
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input ref="inputText" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                    <button onClick={this.props.closeDialog}>Cancel</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var VehiclePlants = React.createClass({

    openDialog: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var myDialog = $('<div>').dialog({
            title: 'Dialog example',
            width: 400,
            close: function (e) {
                React.unmountComponentAtNode(myDialog);
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });

        var closeDialog = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myDialog.dialog('close');
        };
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ReactDOM.renderComponent(<VehiclePlantDialog closeDialog={closeDialog} />, myDialog);
        });
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                    <button onClick={this.openDialog}>Open dialog</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Having this, in my `ejs` file for including `jquery`

```
<% script('/scripts/jquery.js') -%>
<% script('/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js') -%>
```

The include works but, when I click on the **open dialog** button, the console says `dialog is not a function` while if I write it in the console it does.
[image]

Anyone who can help me out?

Note: I am using `Bower`, `Gulp`, `React`, `ReactDom`, `jquery`, `jquery-ui`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the selector

```
$('<div>').dialog({
```

try to inspect $('') from the developer tools.

might be this should work

```
$("<div>My div content</div>").dialog({
```

**EDIT**
Yes you are correct. But there is no problem with you code. It is already working fine.

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44670/)

Comment: This gives me the exact same result. So no, it does not work like that

Comment: @Tikkes i have updated my answer.Yes i was wrong. The code you provided is already working fine. I have created jsfiddle using that.

Comment: I see you have included Babel, might this be the issue I had? Anyway I moved on to `React-Modal` but if it is, I will accept your answer